# How to create a search box in Codeigniter as used in shopping site?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

Hi i want to create search box as used in any shopping site, I have different items which belongs to different categories, which also has sub categories. I want to display the items related to particular category or Sub category as Written inside search textbox. I fetch the items from the mysql database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Can you show your code? Or you are looking for spoon feeding?

Comment: Hi i have been assigned task now itself, I need an idea how it can be done. Is there any library